# Umbraco Newsletter

Tags: umbraco, uninstallation, newsletter

I've installed Umbraco Newsletter, but unfortunately I had to delete it, and install it afterwards, which caused me a lot of headache. Now I am getting all sorts of weird errors in the backoffice(no valForm directives, mailing lists not showing up, circular dependency errors, undefined errors, and more very hard to understand errors). I installed umbraco newsletter as a local package and uninstalled it from the backoffice, simple as that, but something went terribly wrong. My question is : has anyone encountered such a problem after uninstall, what could have caused the error? The problem is that is wrote to the database, and I can't seem to find what is bugging it :(. It's very frustating. Anyone who might have encountered such a problem, please respond :).
GL & HF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that after uninstall I had to reference the NewsletterStudio.dll and Package.Licensing.dll. Hope it helps.